# How to compile MagicalRecord in a Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, magicalrecord

I'm unable to compile the project after adding MagicalRecord, I'm getting this errors:

```
MagicalRecord.h:14:1: error: function definition is not allowed here
MagicalRecord.h:42:28: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'MagicalRecord'
MagicalRecord.h:51:4: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord.h:60:4: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord.h:85:32: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord.h:94:4: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.h:17:1: error: function definition is not allowed here
MagicalRecord+Options.h:43:1: error: function definition is not allowed here
MagicalRecord+Options.h:77:4: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.h:86:49: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.h:95:4: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.h:104:64: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.h:114:4: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.h:124:47: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.h:137:4: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.h:146:27: error: expected a type
MagicalRecord+Options.m:11:8: error: unknown type name 'MagicalRecordLoggingLevel'
MagicalRecord+Options.m:11:63: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MagicalRecordLoggingLevelVerbose'; did you mean 'kMagicalRecordLoggingLevel'?
MagicalRecord+Options.m:12:8: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

how to make it works under a Swift project?
I need a modified version?
there's a plan to release a Swift version of MagicalRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: I followed the errors, and imported the frameworks

looks like a bug in Swift projects

Comment: Hi Marcelo, I have the same issue. How do you solved this? I've put this : #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> #import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"  in my bridging header file but it doesn't work...

Comment: Hello, MagicalRecord thinks that Foundation framework is imported in the .pch file, but a Swift project doesn't have that file, so I solved by manually adding the framework where required

Answer (score 3):

1. It's better to use [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) for managing third-party libraries, MagicalRecord works perfectly when added to project via cocoapods.
2. Seems like you forgot to import Foundation headers in the `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` header file.
3. Make sure `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` selected as 'Objective C Bridging Header' in project build settings
4. MagicalRecord's main include file is `CoreData+MagicalRecord.h`, not `MagicalRecord.h`

Comment: `cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject'` clearly states about missing Foundation headers, added note 3 to my answer.

Comment: This is my Bridging-Header file: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"

Comment: We use `pod 'MagicalRecord/Shorthand', git: 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', branch: 'develop', commit: '77c186ab7a993d9743a6d2dd8ff78088989f65a2'` at present.